# problem with getsymbols when using r shiny

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(quantmod)
ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput(inputId = "Stock",
              label = "Input Stock",),
textOutput<-(outputId="a")

server<-function(input, output){

table<-reactive({
req(input$Stock)
table<-getSymbols("input$Stock",to="2010-01-01",from="2015-01-01",auto.assign=TRUE)
)}
```

I am looking to assign the variable 'table' to the dataset of the output of getsymbols when looking up the stock from the input in shiny, an example potential input is "LLOY.D"

the code

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("LLOY.L",to="2010-01-01",from="2015-01-01",auto.assign=TRUE)
```

works in the normal r console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(quantmod)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("Stock","Input Stock"),
  actionButton("GO","GO"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  data <- eventReactive(input$GO,{
    req(input$Stock)
    getSymbols(input$Stock,src = "yahoo", from="2015-01-01",to="2016-01-01",auto.assign=F)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    data()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi, this is working now thankyou, just another question, if I was wanting to edit this table before outputting it, where would I need to put the code to edit it

Comment: for a little more clarity, I am trying to calculate the moving average of the values in the table